# Import multiple models in runtime into Unity3d scene and make an animation sequence out of it

Tags: unity, animation, models

So, I have multiple models of ply file formats on my phone. When my scene is running, I want to let users import multiple models into `Resource` folder and create an animation sequence in runtime. Is there any way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: The Resource folder and mesh import pipeline do not exist in the Unity runtime after you've built and distributed your game to players. So if you want to parse model files and create meshes from them, that's up to your own code to do. You can read the files with standard file IO methods, and use the `Mesh` class to build the resulting visual representations in memory. Then you can add them to GameObjects with `MeshFilter` & `MeshRenderer` components and transform them or toggle their visibility to create your animation. What one step in that process are you stuck on currently?

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks! I was just confused about how to render them frame by frame. So in each frame, I have to make one model visible and other invisible which gives a perspective of animation?

Comment: That is one possible way to animate, yes. Most game content is animated with another technique called skeletal animation, where we move & rotate parts of the model using a set of bone transforms.

Comment: @DMGregory Yeah! The problem is I am being provided with 100 seperate models and told to make an animation, which is something new to me